# Why is parentNode undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to write a function that takes an ID then traverses up the DOM to see if that item is a child of a tag. This shouldn't be too hard however my `parentNode` is coming back as `undefined`? What am I missing?

Here's a simplified version of my code... thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div id="top">
    <div id="top2"></div>

    <div id="top3"></div>

    <div id="top4"></div>

    <div id="top5">
        <div id="top5_1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="top6">
            <div id="top6_1">
                <a href="" id="findMe">here I am...</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

function findParent(startID, finish){

// change this from id to tag 
start = document.getElementById(startID).tagName;

    while (start.parentNode) {
        start = start.parentNode;

        if (start.tagName === finish){
            console.log("true " + startID + " is a child of " + finish);

        }else{
            console.log("false " + startID + " ISN'T a child of " + finish);
        }

    }
}

findParent("findMe", "BODY");


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `start = document.getElementById(startID);`

Comment: @AlexanderV.B. `startID` is a variable. The error is on which line? `while (start.parentNode)` here?

Comment: You can use `$('#'+startID).parent('#'+finishID).length` to see if the element if a child of `div#hello`

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using `===`? What happens if you change that to `==`?

Comment: @Салман He's not using jQuery. @Tom Walters, *always* use `===` in Javascript. There is never a good reason to use `==`, if you need type coercion, do it manually.

Comment: I think a use of strict comparison operator is never bad, but there's a little cross-browser detail here: some browsers return `tagName` in uppercase, so you need to cast it to lowercase before comparing.

Comment: @Tom Walters - I'm using === for performance reasons, in my app the DOM will be much larger, more complex and it will be constantly repainted.

Comment: @Teemu This has to do with the document type, if it's HTML (4 or 5), it's uppercase, for xhtml it's lowercase. This is mandated by the specs and AFAIK this is consistent across all browsers.

Comment: Well, IE10 with `<!DOCTYPE html>` returns uppercase tag names from `tagName`, all other browsers seem to return tag names in lowercase...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is:

```
start = document.getElementById(startID).tagName;

    while (start.parentNode) {
        start = start.parentNode;
```

You trying to get the `parentNode` from the `tagName`, which is a string.
Remove the `tagName`, and you should be fine.

Comment: Doh! Missed that one there! Thanks